# Using column names "variable" in definition of other columns

Tags: mysql, database

Assume following query:

```
select id, (select count(*) from items) as item_count,
items_stored - (select count(*) from items) from something
```

As i checked out, it's impossible to reuse item_count in following way:

```
select id, (select count(*) from items) as item_count, items_stored - item_count from something
```

As MySQL will print undefined column error.

However, my question is - does using select statement  defined below -will make it execute two times, therfore making query slower? Or is it being cached under the hood (result is same).

```
(select count(*) from items)
```

double usage example:

```
select id, (select count(*) from items) as item_count,
items_stored - (select count(*) from items) from something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the query like this:

```
select 
    tbl.id, 
    tbl.item_count,
    tbl.items_stored -  tbl.item_count
from 
(
    SELECT
        something.id,
        something.items_stored,
        (select count(*) from items) as item_count
    FROM
        something
) as tbl
```

The you count it ones per row in something

Comment: Thanks for tip! Although i'm still curious if we use same query twice like above, whether this will be cached under the hood.